# How do I include all of the bootstrap javascript files into the templates?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

So I have downloaded bootstrap from source through npm, because I wanted to override the stylings for the scss files.
I am able to import the scss files into one scss file and then compile it into a single css file and reference it in my templates.

The stylings work fine but I found out some stuff like dropdown menus, carousels are not working, and realized is probably because I need to import the js files as well.

Now the problem is that I have like more than 15 javascript files from bootstrap and I don't want to  import them all in my templates.


Is there a way to include all of them into a single js file and import to templates?


(p.s what is the difference between the dist and src folder in bootstrap for js?)

Comment: dist folder has the precompiled bundles, src has separate plugins like alert, toast from which bundle was compiled. You need to import the `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Comment: It looks like I don't have that one

Comment: if u did npm install, then it should be under node_modules/bootstrap

Comment: I see, so node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/bootstrap.bundle.min.js ?
hmm i dont see it, only have like some other js files for like dropdown menus or modals and stuff

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/contents/ see here, all these files should be available inside your node_modules

Comment: alr thx, ill look into it

Comment: ok I see, it's actually in bootstrap/dist/js folder instead of bootstrap/js/dist. 
thanks for the help I apprectiate it

Comment: .bundle has bootstrap + popper, so you dont need to install popper separately. But you might have to install jquery..

Comment: I see, but I tried to include bootstrap.bundle.min.js in the template and the server says its 200 meaning its able to get the file but dropdown still doesn't work

Comment: You need to add it in src of angular.json, you could search in stackoverflow on how to add